# How do you pass a list as an argument to a method

Tags: python, list, class, methods, parameters

I'm trying to define a method which takes a python list as one of its input parameters.  By contrast regular functions have no problem accepting lists as input parameters. How Come?

```
    # Simple function that works
    def func(param1, param2):
    for item in param1:
        print item+" "+param2

    var1 = ['sjd', 'jkfgljf', 'poipopo', 'uyuyuyu']
    var2 = 'is nonsense'

    func(var1, var2)

    # Simple function produces the following output:
    # sjd is nonsense
    # jkfgljf is nonsense
    # poipopo is nonsense
    # uyuyuyu is nonsense
```

If I try to get a similar effect with a method inside a class like this:

```
   # Simple class
    class test():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def test_method(par1, par2):
            for itm in par1:
                print itm+" "+par2

    # This executes with no error
    obj = test()

    # This fails
    obj.test_method(var1, var2)

    # Error message will be:
    #   Traceback (most recent call last):
    #     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    #   TypeError: test_method() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Seems like I'm missing something very basic, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not passing self to `test_method`.

Comment: Change to `def test_method(self, par1, par2)`.  The first argument to a method *always* refers to the instance (and is usually named "self").

Comment: the first argument in any method that's defined in a class should be an object, that's usually `self`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `test_method` to have access to data members in your class, then you need to pass *self*, as in:

```
def test_method(self, par1, par2):
```

If `test_method` does not need to have access to data members in your class, then declare it as a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def test_method(par1, par2):
```

For reference, let's say you have a class that holds a number and you want to return said number in a method, and you have another method that gives the product of two numbers, but doesn't depend on anything in your class.  Here's how you would do it:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.number = num

    def getNum(self):
        return self.number

    @staticmethod
    def product(num1,num2):
        return num1*num2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = myClass(4)
    print obj.getNum()
    print myClass.product(2,3)
```

Prints:
4
6

Comment: So the problem had nothing to do with the fact that I was submitting a list as an argument, it would have occurred with any other argument types.  I'll say, that error message is not all that helpful.  Thanks, now I know how and why.

Comment: @user2923409 The reason that the message is ambiguous is because "self" isn't actually a keyword in Python, it's just a convention that basically everyone uses (eclipse's PyDev plugin will actually yell at you if you don't use self).  So, instead of telling you that you missed "self" in your header, it says that you passed three arguments to your function (self, par1, par2) instead of the expected two (par1, par2).  There isn't really anything else that it could say... glad I could help.

Comment: @user2923409 Now, let's say you took in an integer and stored that in `self.number`.  If you then had a method in `myClass` that treated `self.number` as a `list` and iterated through it with a for loop, then if you attempted to run said method, you would get an error saying that `self.number` is not iterable.

Answer (score 2):

Just change:

```
def test_method(par1, par2):
```

to

```
def test_method(self, par1, par2):
```